Do Christians believe that Jews and Muslims go to hell?
As we know, Judaism, Christianity and Islam are the main 3 monotheistic religions.
Quran says:

Surely, those who believed in [God], and those who are Jews, and Christians, and Sabians, -whosoever believes in [God] and in the Last Day, and does good deeds - all such people will have their reward with their Lord, and there will be no reason for them to fear, nor shall they grieve. Surah Al-Baqarah 62

By the way Sabians are also a from a monotheistic religion, John the Baptist was a prophet of them.
From Islam point of view, if you believe God is one and do good deeds then you shouldn’t worry about your salvation.
Is it like this also in Christianity, or is salvation exclusively for Christians?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I would not say all Western Christians do, it varies from church to church, but many do.  Romans 11:25-30 is clear that God's covenant to save the Jews is without exception.  And for Muslims: they don't believe in Jesus the same way that Western Christians do, but as long as thier faith meets the criteria of John 14:6 and Romans 10:13, then they eligible for salvation no matter what else they my be.

The Christian logic is simple: we cannot do good deeds on our own, but need the grace coming from God through Jesus Christ in order to do those good deeds.
After we try so hard to love perfectly but keep failing due to our inherent human nature predisposition to sin, the day we say to God "Help!" is the day when it makes sense for us to see the value of Jesus's sacrifice on the cross, but not before.
On that day it makes sense to ask Jesus to unite His soul to our soul (the term is union with Christ) so Jesus

becomes a means of our sin's forgiveness (we have the responsibility to accept this forgiveness personally)
shares his righteous standing with us so we can also become children of God who (because we are now His children) will then promise to God that we try to live by Jesus's standard (even if we keep failing and trying again)
sends his Holy Spirit to live in us as channel of power (grace) to do good so we start sinning less and loving more.  When Holy Spirit starts living in us, we are called "born again".

This asking is called in Christian parlance "to have faith in Christ as our Lord and Savior", i.e. when we decide to accept God's free gift of reconciliation so we no longer need to fear that God would send us to hell, but would instead approach God as children go to their Father.  This is the day when we start our Christian journey of discipleship which should be marked not only by gratitude towards God, but also solidarity with other Christians who are in the same journey, and especially compassion to those who have not yet seen the benefit of being united with Jesus (i.e. non-Christians).  The day where one "goes public" with the decision to be Jesus's disciple is usually celebrated by public baptism in water witnessed by the whole church.
In reality, there are many people who have not heard, or who misunderstand the gospel, thus not having all available resources to make a decision in their psyche.  For those people, some Christians (i.e. the Inclusivists, see chart in my other answer) believe that "the unevangelized may be saved if they respond in faith to God based on the revelation they have", meaning that if God thinks that the person hasn't had the opportunity to fairly evaluate what Jesus is offering (let's say that person is suffering bad witness from Christians he/she knows), then God would look at how good he/she is having faith in God through the lens of their own religion.
Some Christians believe that on the Day of Judgment (Reckoning, ḥisāb in Islam), Jesus himself will personally be there, at the door between earth and heaven/hell, and he will, with perfect justice, compassion, love, and understanding, take into account whether a person has completely understood the gospel.  If he/she has not, He himself will preach to the person on the spot.  A person who has tried to be good all his/her life based on imperfect information about Jesus, would naturally say "Yes, I have faith in you" and then pass to heaven.
CONCLUSION: Just because one identifies as a Jew or a Moslem does not automatically mean they go to hell; it depends on their honest appraisal and acceptance of the gospel over their lifetime.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

There are two kinds of Christianity that will give you two different answers.
The first kind believes that we are saved by the works that God graciously performs in us. The second group believes that we are not saved by our works that God performs in us, but are saved by Christ’s works, apart from our own works altogether.
Both kinds of Christianity preach works and expect works, for there is no true faith without works (as obviously what we genuinely believe affects our behavior), but each kind views the cause of their salvation differently and on opposite grounds. One is based on the involvement of their works, the other not on their works.
Those who believe the first kind of Christianity (that they are saved by their works they do by God’s grace) follow the Roman Catholic doctrine.  Those who trust God in their salvation and put it all on faith, apart from works, who then produce works not to be saved but to express their gratitude for their salvation, are called Protestants, so called because they revolted from what they considered to be doctrinal corruption of what the scriptures teach on this point.  The Protestants were not a small sect slowly growing but a large split due to their disagreement with Catholics on the basis of salvation.
As far as I know, most other groups that call themselves Christian but who are neither Catholic nor Protestant, follow the Catholic view in one shape or another. In other words, they do not rely only on what Scripture teaches and only on Christ’s work for their salvation, during the period when they were still enemies of Christ, not possessing any ability to do any good work.  They rely on some kind of human work and human tradition, assisted by God’s grace that they cooperate with, in their achievements.
The only book in the world that promises salvation by faith rather than by works is the Bible. It is the only lamp to our feet.

Romans 4:4-5 ESV
[4] Now to the one who works, his wages are not counted as a gift but
as his due. [5] And to the one who does not work but believes in him
who justifies the ungodly, his faith is counted as righteousness.

As a Muslim there is probably some recognition that Abraham was a man of God. The scripture also argues that Abraham was an example of someone who is considered righteous apart from any consideration of works, but solely by faith in the Messiah being promised to him.  This example we should follow.
Again, in the book of Romans, the Bible mentions how Abraham had faith in the promised Messiah and how he was saved by faith to become an example for us; he was not saved by the gracious works he had performed.

Romans 4:23-25 ESV
[23] But the words “it was counted to him” were not written for his
sake alone, [24] but for ours also. It will be counted to us who
believe in him who raised from the dead Jesus our Lord, [25] who was
delivered up for our trespasses and raised for our justification.

Now I will answer the question. If a Muslim or a Jew has heard and believed that Christ died for him and if he repents from his past ways of thinking (ie. about doing works and attempting to obey the laws of conscience or the laws of Moses) but with the opposite repented view believes instead in the God-man Jesus, in his death and his perfect obedience to God's law as the means for saving him, and if that person accepts God's declaring him fully righteous and fully forgiven, then he will be saved. This person is then ‘saved by faith’ in Christ and renounces his own righteousness altogether.  He gives God glory by doing so.
The scripture also says that we should not ask, now that this truth has been made known: ‘Who will be saved?’, ‘Will a Muslim be saved?’  The Hebrews had a proverbial saying from old passages in the Bible that something ‘far above’ or ‘far below’ was hidden and impossible to know. But this question of yours is no longer a hidden mystery because it has been plainly revealed that Christ was put to death for your sin and raised for your justification.   The reason why you asked is therefore because you have not yet heard and believed this good news in the gospel.

Romans 10:5-13 ESV
[5] For Moses writes about the righteousness that is based on the law,
that the person who does the commandments shall live by them. [6] But
the righteousness based on faith says, “Do not say in your heart, ‘Who
will ascend into heaven?’” (that is, to bring Christ down) [7] “or
‘Who will descend into the abyss?’” (that is, to bring Christ up from
the dead). [8] But what does it say? “The word is near you, in your
mouth and in your heart” (that is, the word of faith that we
proclaim); [9] because, if you confess with your mouth that Jesus is
Lord and believe in your heart that God raised him from the dead, you
will be saved. [10] For with the heart one believes and is justified,
and with the mouth one confesses and is saved. [11] For the Scripture
says, “Everyone who believes in him will not be put to shame.” [12]
For there is no distinction between Jew and Greek; for the same Lord
is Lord of all, bestowing his riches on all who call on him. [13] For
“everyone who calls on the name of the Lord will be saved.”

It seems then, the answer is so clear if we just believe what the Bible says, then we do not need to ask the question.  Only those who trust Christ for their salvation will be saved. This obviously excludes all those who say they do not.

There are two kinds of people in the world in the world, those that divide people into two groups and those that don't. There are other options than those you've listed. Yes, it's true. Not all Christians believe one or the other, and they are still Christians.

This is an inaccurate description of the Catholic-Protestant schism. Catholics do not deny the necessity of Christ's works, and Protestentism is not defined by sola fide. Methodists and Anabaptists are Protestant, but they do not teach sola fide.

There are very many different Christian groups or denominations, my view as a Christian is that both Jews and Muslims have rejected the sonship of Jesus as the Son of God. This is the only thing that threatens their condemnation to the lake of fire, because John 3:16 clearly says that God sent his one and only begotten Son into the world, and there is another phrase that follows this and it says that whosoever believes in Him as God's son and his teachings will have life everlasting.
The Jews rejected his Sonship as the Messiah simply because he didn't fit their expectations of the promised Messiah because they applied their human wisdom to scripture and understood the Messiah to be a king who will crush Israel's enemies North and South, contrary to this Jesus was going to be both a physical and spiritual king who will establish his Messianic kingdom on earth in a future time
Muslims then teach falsely that Jesus wasn't crucified and that God saved him before the Jews could touch him, this is not the case because Jesus had prophesied to his disciples that he must be delivered into the hands of sinners, suffer then die and on the third day, rise from the dead, which was God's plan all along to reverse the death curse inflicted on the world through the sin of Adam and restore eternity to the human race.
Both Jews and Muslims tried to bend the truth to fit to their own views because the Jew wanted a Jewish king who would conquer the whole world in the name of Israel but God wanted to graft in the gentiles so they would also come to the knowledge of the truth and be saved.
The Muslim then said it is not possible for God's son to be killed by men because God caught him up to heaven before the Jews could kill him but he was crucified and showed his disciples the holes on the hands, feet on the risen body.
BOTTOM LINE: No other name has been given above or below by which we are saved save for the name of Jesus who is also the Christ, Salvation is only through believing in Jesus

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I am a Christian and I do not know. It does not work on this way. You can not get answers by finding some hadith or talmud verse about your problem, because there is no such thing in Christianity.
Of course there are wise texts written by... extraordinary people and it is useful to read them.
John 14:6, Jesus said: "I am the way and the truth and the life. No one comes to the Father except through me." (with context)
Possible interpretations. These are only what I see into the text:

Jesus decides case by case, thus also Muslims
Only Christians, except if Jesus recognizes the Muslims as Christians
Only Roman Catholics (current Roman Catholic Church does not think it so!)
Anyone believing Him, thus also Muslims

Reality is that we do not have a clear vision about such things. We do not know. We live our whole life while we do not know. Only hope.

This question has been contemplated by Christian theologians for some time and is answered by the "greatest commandment".
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Commandment
Those that love their neighbors as they love themselves, and believe in some higher power above all, will reach heaven.  Jesus Christ came to Earth more than 2000 years ago and there's been humans on Earth long before that.  Christians do not believe all humans born before Christ came to Earth should be sent to hell because they did not know Jesus.  It was impossible for any human to know Jesus before something like 30 AD when Jesus shifted his occupation from a carpenter to evangelist.  Even then most of the world would be ignorant of Jesus due to the poor communications of the day.  It took another 1500 years or so before word of the life of Jesus could reach over oceans.
Even without the influence of Jesus Christ on earth any person could reach heaven by being kind to others and having some belief in some omnipotent and omniscient being.
I don't know what this means for people's that believed in multiple deities.  There's some cultures that believe in something of a "holy trinity" like Christians which by some interpretations could be a path to heaven by Christian theologians.  There's the idea of a creator, preserver, and destroyer in some religions that may be a kind of "holy trinity".  There's the idea of a past, present, and future which is a parallel of this idea.
There is the prohibition by God in the Christian Bible to not worship false gods.  That could cause problems with some interpretations on the conditions to get into heaven.  The Christian god isn't going to punish people for ignorance, since it is understood that children will reach heaven if they die because they are innocent from any sin as they lack the ability to understand the repercussions of anything they do.  This is the idea behind the Christian confirmation process, young adults "confirm" their infant baptism through study of what it means to be a good person since as an adult God will hold them responsible for their actions.  Some Christian religions don't believe in infant baptism, instead having baptism as adults with perhaps the "confirmation" as other denominations understand the concept being a part of the ceremony.
A person that is an adherent to one of the Abrahamic religions would know the Christian God and so meets one of the two great commandments.  The other great commandment is to treat others with kindness.  A Muslim or Jew would likely have a better than average chance to get into heaven for having known God as Christians know God.  The rest is just not being an a-hole to others.

Ok but having more knowledge we also have more responsibility.

Is God only the God of the Jews? Or only the God of the Christians? God is the God of all - and he desires that all be saved. It is true that salvation is of the Jews and through Jesus Christ, but it is intended as a blessing for all.
The important thing for salvation is not your doctrines. The purpose of doctrines and belief is that they serve to guide you and your actions - and it is your actions that you are judged by. Belief alone cannot save you (James 2).
Let us consider the biblical model of salvation. Who are those that were saved from the flood? Was it not Noah - who was deemed righteous - and those who were close to Noah: his wife and sons and their wives? And, of course, all the animals that God called to the Ark.
And during the death of the firstborn, the 10th plague in Egypt, who are those that Moses instructed concerning the Passover that they may live? Unlike the plague of Hail, he did not instruct the Egyptians concerning the Passover Lamb/Goat - but only His People, the Hebrews.
Likewise, in the parable of the 10 virgins, the ones who were not ready when the Lord was coming left to prepare. He came when they were away and he shut the doors. When these virgins returned and presented themselves and asked to be let in, he replied: ‘Truly I say to you, I do not know you.’ And so the virgins were denied entry to the wedding. (Matthew 25:1-13).
The important thing for salvation, then, is not do you know about God or of Christ: but does the Lord know you? Will Christ acknowledge you before God?
If you want to be acknowledged by Christ, if you want to be known by God, then here is a good guide: the one through whom the love of God is made known to the least of these shall through the least of these be made known to God.

Matthew 25:37-40 Then the righteous will answer Him, ‘Lord, when did we see You hungry, and feed You, or thirsty, and give You something to drink? 38 And when did we see You as a stranger, and invite You in, or naked, and clothe You? 39 And when did we see You sick, or in prison, and come to You?’ 40 And the King will answer and say to them, ‘Truly I say to you, to the extent that you did it for one of the least of these brothers or sisters of Mine, you did it for Me.’


Proverbs 19:17 One who is gracious to a poor person lends to the Lord,
And He will repay him for his good deed.

More generally, Christ says that those who are his brothers and sisters and even mother are those who do the will of His Father.

Matthew 12:46-50  While He was still speaking to the crowds, behold, His mother and brothers were standing outside, seeking to speak to Him. 47 [[an]Someone said to Him, “Look, Your mother and Your brothers are standing outside, seeking to speak to You.”] 48 But [ao]Jesus replied to the one who was telling Him and said, “Who is My mother, and who are My brothers?” 49 And extending His hand toward His disciples, He said, “Behold: My mother and My brothers! 50 For whoever does the will of My Father who is in heaven, he is My brother, and sister, and mother.”

To directly answer your question: some Jews will go to hell, as well some Muslims and even some Christians. But also, there will be Jews and Muslims and Christians, and Atheists and Agnostics, etc. who will be saved - for they are known by God.
